# Skip non-alphabetical characters with BreakIterator

Tags: java

My goal from this is to convert "<,Bold,>" to "< Bold>" (Without the space between '<' & 'B') using BreakIterator

Say String " This is a test." is my input

```
public static List<String> getWords(String text) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BreakIterator breakIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    breakIterator.setText(text);
    int lastIndex = breakIterator.first();
    while (BreakIterator.DONE != lastIndex) {
        int firstIndex = lastIndex;
        lastIndex = breakIterator.next();
        if (lastIndex != BreakIterator.DONE) {
            String t = text.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);
            words.add(t);
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

getWords(String) returns <,Bold,>, ,This, ,is, ,a, ,test.

I've tried :

```
            String t = text.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);
            if (t != "<" || t != ">" || t != "/" || t != ">") System.out.println("Char Not Skipped " + t); else System.out.println("Char Skipped" + t);
            //if (text.charAt (firstIndex - 1) == '<') t = "<" + t;
            //if (text.charAt (lastIndex + 1) == '>') t += ">";
            //if (text.charAt (lastIndex + 1) == '/' && text.charAt (lastIndex + 2) == '>') t += "/>";
            //System.out.println(t);
            words.add(t);
```

All that returns is Char Not Skipped.

Comment: I never used that. But `replaceAll(regex)` is a better option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question the right way.

If you want to delet all `,` in your string you could easily do:

```
    String s = "<,Bold,>, ,This, ,is, ,a, ,test";
    String newString = s.replace(",", "");
    System.out.println(newString);
```

The output would look like that:

> This is a test

If you just want to delet `<,` and `,>` you could use:

```
   String s = "<,Bold,>, ,This, ,is, ,a, ,test";   
   String newString =  (s.replace("<,", "<")).replace(",>", ">");
   System.out.println(newString);
```

Output of that would be

> `<Bold>`, ,This, ,is, ,a, ,test

Comment: Using this I am getting  : `<Bold> This is a test`